# Get dynamic Id from dynamic span element

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have a span that is created dynamic from javascript but when i try to get the element by id returns null

Here is how I populate the span from an external javascript:

```
function createResponseNode() {
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.className = "clearfix  container  col-8 right  card  p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white  text-right ";
    node.innerHTML = "...";
    resultDiv.appendChild(node);
    return node;
}
```

Here is the span that retrieve the response from javascript

```
<div class="col s5 " id="wrp">
    <h5>Response payload:</h5>
    <span id="jsonResponse" name="response"></span>
</div>

<script>
    var text = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(text);
</script>
```

I can use java code because i use jsp, but also it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't actually have any 'document.getElementById' call in it, and your function to create your div is not actually setting an ID on the div, so you wouldn't be able to find it that way anyway.

Somewhere in your dynamically created div you want to run

`node.setAttribute("id", "MyDivId");`

Which you can then perform a lookup using

`document.getElementById("MyDivId");`

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried with this var txt=document.getElementById("jsonResponse");  but doesn't work as well

Comment: Did you ensure that "resultDiv" in the function to populate the jsonResponse is definitely picking the correct div.

Comment: Just had a thought, are you perhaps performing an ajax call to retrieve some data in jsonResponse and then attempting to write that data to the span? You may be trying to write the response before the ajax data has had a chance to return. You may need to pass the 'createResponseNode' function as a callback to the ajax call. Have a look at the example here - https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp